# Check if any value in a Rust HashMap is greater than zero

Tags: hashmap, rust, any

I want to check if a `HashMap<i32, i32>` contains any values greater than zero. I have this code:

```
let has_demand = minimums.iter().any(|*x| x > 0)
```

which fails. The problem is with `|*x|`, but I don't know what to put there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bad syntax. You should use `&x`, which is a reference (not `*x`, which is a dereference).

It is a `HashMap` (not a `Vec`), so to check values, you need to iterate through the values (not the entire `HashMap`).

Example code:

```
let value_exists = hashmap.values().any(|&x| x > 0);
```

Please check out the docs:

- [`Iterator::any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any)
- [`HashMap::values`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.values)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me a lot. If you post the final line of code I will also accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is

```
let has_demand = minimums.values().any(|&x| x > 0);
```